# How to send an RTS 802.11 packet using Scapy (and get a CTS response)

Tags: macos, scapy, packet, wifi

I'm quite new to Scapy, and I'm trying to craft an RTS packet and send it to an AP, in order to get a CTS response. However, I'm having a really hard time figuring out the proper way to do it (being a beginner in networking and 802.11 packets doesn't help either).

This is the code I have for now:

```py
bytes = struct.pack("<H", 123) # 123 microseconds
timeval = struct.unpack(">H", bytes)[0]
pkt = RadioTap()/Dot11(addr1 = target_addr, addr2 = my_addr, type = 1, subtype = 11, ID = timeval)
```

I know that `type` must be equal to 1 since it's a Control packet, and that `subtype` must be equal to 11 because it's an RTS packet. However, when I send the packet with either `sr()` or `srp()` or `sr1()` I either get no response back (Scapy waits for a response but nothing gets back so it just continues waiting) or I get the exact message I sent.

[This question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/130590/sending-probe-request-frames-receving-probe-response-scapy) mentions adding a `Dot11Elt()` layer at the end, however that changes nothing in my case.

This is the type of response I get back:
[image: Scapy RTS result]

And if I open the 0th element of the response tuple with Wireshark, I get:
[image: Wireshark analysis of response]

I've hidden the MAC addresses, but they are the sameas those I put in the packet I sent to the AP (`target_addr` and `my_addr`). I'm expecting to get back a CTS  with `my_addr` as "destination address".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to ask this question on the Github tracker. It looks like it might be a bug (but I'll need to check the details)